# Accessing the numeric key value of json objects from large json file <solved>

Tags: jquery, json

I have tried to access the key value of these JSON object in the picture but is it even possible?

I'm using PHP/Javascript to access the data from another page.

What I'm looking for is to retrieve the number values before the actual array of data (red underline in the picture)

[image]

edit: what I was looking for was:

obj.attractions;
Object.keys(obj.attractions);

Thank you for answers.

Comment: To help you, please add your code to the question

Comment: Does this work for you: `obj.attractions["1844"]`

Comment: Or do you mean this: `Object.keys(obj.attractions)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get them with `Object.keys()`

```js
var obj = {
  attractions: {
    1844: { 'key1' : 'value1',
            'key2' : 'value2'},
    1845: { 'key3' : 'value3',
            'key4' : 'value4'},
    1846: { 'key5' : 'value5',
            'key6' : 'value6'}
  }
}

alert(Object.keys(obj.attractions));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,I hope it may help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Convert a JavaScript object into a JSON string, and send it to the server.</h2>

<script>
var myObj = {
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(Object.keys(myObj.quiz))
</script>

</body>
</html>
```